# Can you use hacked drones to attack other enemies?

Tags: invisible-inc

According to the [Invisible Inc Wikia](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies), some drones are equipped with weapons, including the Obake drones of Sankaku Corportation.

Can you use a hacked drone to attack other enemies?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/40198-dealing-with-drones/#entry530124) in the Klei forums, *yes*, it is possible to use hacked drones to attack other enemies, as long as the drone has weapons installed:

> Using them *only* for attacking is missing their potential.
>
> And I never said hack them and attack. I just noted IF you use them to
>   attack, they are a one shot weapon.

Comment: I know drones with weapons have a limit, but I thought it was more than a single shot (maybe 2?). Though core game encourages stealth, Draco benefits from corpses; using drones helps preserve ammunition.

Comment: Akuma drones at least don't have one-shot weapons. See [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334346/8557) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've got out of a few sticky situations by hacking a nearby Obake drone and getting them to kill a guard threatening one of my agents.

This has all of the usual disadvantages of killing guards, of course. Drones also have limited ammunition, so hacking an Okabe for a third time I found it out of ammo. Also, Obakes can kill each other, so in one game I used one Obake to kill another after it had run out of ammo, clearing the way for my other agents to get past it.

I find it is generally best to avoid killing or even knocking out guards, due to the escalation that causes, but sometimes it's the only way.

Comment: Why the delete and down votes? This is direct evidence from personal experience with the most recent release version of the game, rather than second hand evidence from a version a few years old, which got some of the details (ammo capacity) wrong.